# Best way to find correlation between categorical response variables and continuous explanatory variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

Sorry if this is a really simple question, but I'm very new to multivariable statistics and I'm trying to find a best method to deal with my ecological dataset. 
I recorded the environmental parameters (`temperature`, `humidity` and `light`) of each survey site that I found specific plants (`PlantA`, `PlantB`, ...).

For example, a reduced version of my dataset would look something like this:

```
SiteID  temperature  humidity  light   PlantA   PlantB   PlantC   PlantD     ...
1         80           0.7       200     Y        N        Y        N        ...
2         90           0.9       150     N        N        Y        N        ...
3         75           0.85      175     N        Y        N        N        ...
4         80           0.9       180     N        Y        Y        N        ...
```

I'm trying to see which explanatory variables can best explain the presence of specific plants, so that I can say something like "light is the most important factor in explaining the presene of Plant A" and such.

I tried running a logistic regression in R with the `glm` function but couldn't build a good model, as all my z values were 0 and Pr(>z) were 1. I'm suspecting that the number of my observations are too low for me to include all my predictors, as I have 15 predictors and only 30 observations.

So I think my next step should be to reduce my explanatory variables, like how NMDS can reduce the number of dimensions. (I think NMDS may be better than PCoA since PCoA assumes a linear relationship, which wouldn't be necessarily true for my data)

I'm not sure how to fit in my binary variables into NMDS though, as all the (few) examples I've found so far didn't include binary variables in their example dataset. 1) Would just treating `Y` as `1` and `N` as `0` work? 2) Also, since I'm trying to find the importance of the explanatory variables on each of my response variable, would it make more sense to cut off the data for each plants for each NMDS analysis, like below?

```
Data 1
SiteID  temperature  humidity  light   PlantA  
1         80           0.7       200     Y      
2         90           0.9       150     N      
3         75           0.85      175     N      
4         80           0.9       180     N      
Data 2
SiteID  temperature  humidity  light   PlantB 
1         80           0.7       200     N      
2         90           0.9       150     N      
3         75           0.85      175     Y      
4         80           0.9       180     Y
```

...

Comment: To echo CatM's response, your biggest challenge will be your sample size. PCA or another dimensionality reduction method like combining correlated variables will be helpful but if your goal is inference (estimating odds ratios and informative confidence intervals) 30 samples is rather low. If possible, I'd gather more data because even with 4 covariates 30 samples the confidence intervals will probably be rather large and may not offer much insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to be able to write this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation. From what I read it does seem that running a glm would be the best approach but looking at your variables I think you may have multicollinearity, I am pretty sure light and temperature capturing something very similar even though not exactly the same construct. I would potentially run correlations between predictors and then, if you do have high correlations between variables, I would run a PCA so that you would be able to determine which variables to keep. If you then get to a stage you only have 4 variables, maybe you will be able to fit a glm, though only 30 observations seems quite a low number.

Comment: You're right, light and temperature (or the other variables I didn't include here) are not completely independent from each other. By "running correlations between predictors", do you mean that I should do a simple linear regression/ANOVA between my predictors to see if I get high R2, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Just run some Pearson/Spearman correlations and see if there is some high correlations in there. If there are, I would go with a PCA and then run the model. Otherwise you have too many predictors that basically reflect the same construct.